# Copying an Object Across a Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook which displays a little coloured box based on some input metrics from another worksheet within the workbook. I want to display these little coloured boxes in an additional worksheet in the workbook. Is there a way to copy a shape across worksheets so that the colour will still update with the metrics rather than using the code again for a separate worksheet?

I essentially want to display this textbox with the coloured boxes/arrows in another worksheet as well.

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand, but take a look at the camera tool: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/oddity/the_camera_tool/

Comment: maaaah.... I was to slow :P

Comment: It wouldn't let me use that method as my boxes are just drawn shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty dirty way to do something like this would be the Indirect-Picture-Copy-Solution.

Asume the art is at Sheet1 B2:D8 then just input a picture in Sheet2 (the picture doesn't matter, just pick the first you can find)

While the Picture is selected input in the formula bar `=Sheet1!B2:D8`.

Hope that helps ;)

**EDIT**

For making it dynamically put in any module:

```
Public Function testing() As Range
  Set testing = Range(Sheet1.Shapes("Dia 1").TopLeftCell, Sheet1.Shapes("Dia 1").BottomRightCell)
End Function
```

(Make sure to change the names to fit your workbook/sheet/shapes....-names)

Then define a name (I'll pick TETE for this example)

Refers to: `=testing()`

Then the picture-formula is: `=TETE`

Whenever the size or position changes, your picture fits to it... still not a good way to solve your problem (to my eye)

Funny fact: making the picture-formula directly to `=testing()` will just pop an error

Comment: I never noticed you could do it that way. Doesn't necessarily seem that "dirty" even.

Comment: The only issue is the shapes don't have a cell reference as they're just floating, is there a way to get around that? Thanks

Comment: As long as the Shape doesn't change it's position, it's no big deal... else you would need something like in my edit...

Comment: The only thing that changes with the shape is the colour but it doesn't seem to update using the above method

Comment: Huh.... Worked for me without anything to complain about. Maybe there is something I do not notice with my "self made" example. At least, I would do something like this at a seperate worksheet as text and (conditional) formatting in cells and then use the pic in the first place (cus I need it 2 times)... this way there is no need for VBA at all (at least when just doing that)

Comment: @DirkReichel eventually got it working, thank you very much!